# Entity Framework Code First model from Database design

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm working on understanding EF (using EF6).  I want to go the code first route as that seems to be the trend.  What I'm trying to do is figure out how to model what would be multiple join tables in an EF model.

My main entities are Staff and School.  A staff member could work at multiple schools in multiple Roles (Computer, 1st grade, History, Custodian, etc.).

An example: Teacher Bob Jones teaches Computers at Lincoln Elementary and Alpha Science at Truman Elementary.

From a database table design, I would likely have tables for:
- Staff
- School
- StaffRole - Lookup table with the different roles
- SchoolStaffRole - Join of Staff, School, & StaffRole

However, I'm not quite sure what my EF models would look like.  I started with the following, but it obviously doesn't make the relationships properly.  What is a valid method?  Is it that I need a SchoolStaffRole class and that's what's referenced in the Staff and School models?

```
class School
{
    int ID{get;}
    virtual ICollection<Staff> Staff{get;set;}
}
class Staff : Member
{
    int ID{get;}
    virtual ICollection<School> Schools{get;set;}
    virtual ICollection<SchoolRole> Roles{get;set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would useful if could add the SQL tables that you are trying to map into to your question

try avoid inheritance as much as you can, `Staff :Member` is not going to be fun

in any case give this a try

```
public class Staff : Member
{
    public int ID{get;set;}

}
public class School 
{
    public int ID{get;set;}

}


public class SchoolStaff 
{
    public int ID{get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("School")]
    public int SchoolID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("SchoolID")]
    public virtual School School {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("Staff")]
    public int StaffID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("StaffID")]
    public virtual Staff Staff {get;set;}

    virtual ICollection<SchoolStaffRole> Roles{get;set;}
}


 public class SchoolStaffRole 
{
    public int ID{get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("SchoolStaff")]
    public int SchoolStaffID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("SchoolStaffID")]
    public virtual SchoolStaff SchoolStaff {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey("SchoolRole")]
    public int SchoolRoleID {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("SchoolRoleID")]
    public virtual SchoolRole SchoolRole {get;set;}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn code first, the fastest way I found is have EF generate the code first code for you.. then explore the generated code.  When you add the entity data model to your project, select code first from database.